# A recurrence relation with two variables

Tags: co.combinatorics, mp.mathematical-physics, gm.general-mathematics, recurrences

How to solve the following recurrence relation?

$$f(i,j) = 2 f(i,j-1) + (\alpha^j+\beta^j) f(i-1,j), 0<\alpha,\beta < 1$$

With the boundary condition

$$ f(0,0) = f(1,0) = f(0,1) = 1 $$

A special case that I can solve is $\alpha = \beta$,
$$f(i,j) = 2 f(i,j-1) + 2 \alpha^j f(i-1,j)$$
$$ f(i,j) = 2^{i+j} \binom{i+j}{i}_{\alpha} $$
where $\binom{i+j}{i}_{\alpha}$ is the Gaussian binomial coefficient.

Comment: um.. $\sum_{k=0}^{j} \binom{j}{k} \alpha^k \beta^{j-k} = (\alpha+\beta)^j$?

Comment: @mathworker21 Thank you for the reminder. I made a huge mistake in the description. I've correctted that.